# Click event of stacked line chart not working

Tags: javascript, chart.js, linechart

I'm designing a line chart with stacked area. On click of chart, the chart method `getElementsAtEvent()` is returning empty array.

On the click event function, I need the x-axis data points.

Below is the Chart config (reduced dataset) and onclick event details:

```
var chartData = {
  labels: ['10:20', '10:25', '10:30', '10:35', '10:40', '10:45', '10:50', '10:55', '11:00', '11:05', '11:10', '11:15'],
  fill: true,
  datasets: [{
      label: 'First   ',
      borderColor: '#bada55',
      backgroundColor: '#bada55',
      data: [40, 20, 10, 10, 30, 60, 50, 55, 60, 70, 40, 45]
    },
    {
      label: 'My Second dataset',
      borderColor: '#44dd11',
      backgroundColor: '#44dd11',
      data: [20, 10, 5, 5, 15, 30, 25, 27, 20, 15, 20, 22]
    },
    {},
    {}
  ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks: {
          fontSize: 10
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        display: false,
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks: {
          fontSize: 10,
          min: 0,
          max: 100
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
document.getElementById("myChart").onclick = function(evt) {
  var activePoints = myChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
  var firstPoint = activePoints[0];
  var label = myChart.data.labels[firstPoint._index];
  var value = myChart.data.datasets[firstPoint._datasetIndex].data[firstPoint._index];
  if (firstPoint !== undefined)
    alert(label + ": " + value);
};
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha19ozqy/283/) with full dataset

Comment: Do you need the array of `data` or just the value of the one clicked on?

Comment: @Matt I need an array of data with x-axis and Y-axis data points.

Comment: So clicking on one will return [20, 10, 5, 5, 15...]?

Comment: I specifically need x-axis point on click. for e.g. `10:20` or `10:40`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you are wanting correctly then this should work for you.

```
document.getElementById("myChart").onclick = function(evt) {
    var active = myChart.getElementAtEvent(event)[0]._index;
    var value = myChart.getElementAtEvent(event)[0]._chart.config.data.labels[active];
    alert(value);
};
```

Active simply finds the index of where you clicked and then it's used at the end of `value` to find where in your `labels` that item correlates to.

If this is incorrect in what you want please let me know.

**Edit 1**

Based on wanting to click anywhere I took it as anywhere within the alley from where the point is to the next. You can try the following:

```
document.getElementById("myChart").onclick = function(evt, array) { 
    var xLabel = myChart.scales['x-axis-0'].getValueForPixel(evt.x);    
    alert(myChart.config.data.labels[xLabel - 1]);
};
```

Comment: above logic works when clicked on the individual datapoints. The user can click any where in plotted graph.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking/saying.

Comment: click any where in the graph to get values

Comment: @ShashiSingh Check Edit 1 and let me know if that is what you are more referring to.

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha19ozqy/286/) with Edit1 function return error `getValueForPixel` is not a function

Comment: You are also getting a warning to download moment.js due to you using an old chart.js..a beta 2.0.0. change it to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js and fly.

Comment: Also, I used  `myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'index', { intersect: false })` and it worked well

Comment: can you please send a link to the detail docs of chart.js. The chartjs website has not mentioned all the methods

Comment: There isn't really any other great place to get that information. Some of it comes from previous experience, some of it comes from consoling the chart object and going through the properties to learn about them, and most of it comes from looking at what other people have discovered and building off of that. I believe the Chart.js documentation is the most, single collective information source available.